# submenu for child in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a `ExpandableListView` in my XML, by using `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, I created a parent list and child lists. When I click on a parent list item, the submenu will open (child List).

Now my problem that I want create submenu for child List and when I click on each sub menu(child List) open another sub menu. For example, for *red 1*, I want create a submenu and when I click on "red 1" link parent list open submenu

[image]

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

String [] parentList= {"red","blue","green"};

String [][] childList = {{"red 1","red 2","red 3"},
                        {"blue 1","blue 2","blue 3"},
                        {"green 1","green 2","green 3"}};


Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context){

    this.context=context;

}
@Override

public int getGroupCount() {
    return parentList.length;

}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int parentPosition) {
    return childList[parentPosition].length;

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int parentPosition) {
    return parentList[parentPosition];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childList[parentPosition][childPosition] ;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int parentPosition) {
    return parentPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int parentPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(parentList[parentPosition]);
    textView.setPadding(140,0,0,0);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    return textView;

}

@Override
public View getChildView(int parentPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(childList[parentPosition][childPosition]);
    textView.setPadding(175, 0, 0, 0);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return textView;}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Share what you have implemented so far, it will make it easier for us to help you based on an existing code.

Comment: is my code , u can see now , i dont know how to add another submenu near my childList